# Maclaurin expansion to calculate $1/\sqrt{e}$ to 5 decimal places

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm not sure where to start with this. I know it is a summation but I don't know how to find what the summation is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. We have that 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}=e^{-1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1/2)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k k!}.$$
Note that the [series is alternating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series), therefore
$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^kk!}-e^{-1/2}\right|\leq \frac{1}{2^N N!}.$$

Answer (score 0):

A couple of alternative approaches:

1. $$\int_{0}^{1/2}x^4(1-x)^4 e^{-x}\,dx = \frac{-10139873+6150144 \sqrt{e}}{256 \sqrt{e}}$$
   hence $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\approx\frac{6150144}{10139773}=\color{green}{0.6065306}\ldots $
2. By Gauss continued fraction for $\tanh$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$ has the following ordinary continued fraction:
   $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}=\left[0,1,1,\color{blue}{1,1,5},\color{green}{1,1,9},\color{purple}{1,1,13},\color{red}{1,1,17},\color{orange}{1,1,21},\ldots\right]$$
   hence a simpler and more accurate approximation of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$ is $\color{green}{\frac{10049}{16568}}$.